# Aurelia: How to access data stored in a child-router's view-model

Tags: aurelia

I am fairly new to Aurelia and I am trying to understand what’s the best way to access and display data in a subpage of a child-router. The data is stored in the activate method of the child-router’s view-model. My Problem is to display the data when I first enter or reload a subpage of the child-router. Unfortunately it's not working. As soon as I have displayed a subpage and go to another, it all works fine.

child-router.js

```
export class ChildRouter {
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = 'Child Router Title';
        config.map([
            { route: '', redirect: 'basics'},
            { route: ['basics', ''],    name: 'basics',   moduleId: './basics/basics',      nav: true, title: 'Basics' },
            { route: 'data',            name: 'data',     moduleId: './data/data',          nav: true, title: 'Data' }
        ]);
        this.router = router;
    }
    activate() {
        this.var1 = "Var1. Only works when I reenter a subpage.";
        this.var2 = "Var2. Only works when I reenter a subpage.";
    }
}
```

child-router.html

```
<template>
  <require from="../components/detail-navigation.html"></require>
  <h2>${router.title}</h2>
  <detail-navigation router.bind="router"></detail-navigation>
  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

basics.html

```
<template>
  <h2>Basics Title</h2>
  <h3>${var1}</h3>
</template>
```

data.html

```
<template>
  <h2>Data Title</h2>
  <h3>${var2}</h3>
</template>
```

I hope you understand my problem.

[Here is a link to a test projekt on git.](https://github.com/dhuebschmann/Aurelia-Child-Router-Test)

I am looking forward for any recommendations.

Comment: The `ChildRouter` is a normal page right, with a view and a view-model? Do you want to display the data in your `ChildRouter` view, or do you want to display the data in the page that the router will render?

Comment: Yes exactly. The ChildRouter is a normal page. I want to display the data in the page (basics.html and data.html) that the router will render with the router-view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would really recommend you not try to do this. This is introducing tight coupling between the `ChildRouter` page and any pages displayed as routes on it. If you need these pages to talk to each other, consider using the Dependency Injection provider to inject an instance of the same class in to each page and sharing information that way.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ashley. It works now fine with Dependency Injection.